# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. ONLY when using Python from nodejs, python-shell

Tags: python, node.js, numpy, libraries

I am running a python script from nodejs using python-shell. I am trying to import numpy (or any module). However I am getting the DLL load failed error. Numpy or any other module gets imported fine from command prompt or any other place.

I have compared the sys.path from running the script from nodejs (which doesnt work) as well as from the VS CODE terminal (which works). They are exactly the same.
I have also compared the python excutable which is exactly the same.

This is what my Python path looks like :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python36.zip
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\DLLs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages

Why could I be getting this error?

Comment: How did you install Python?  Windows executables and DLLs depend on entries in your `PATH` environment variable to find other DLLs on which they depend, so that is the most likely culprit.  See if there's a noticeable `PATH` difference in the two cases.

Comment: @Iguananaut I am using the Python executable from Visual Studio. But I did create a new environment and try with pip install python too. The paths are exactly the same!